# Python:: tkinter OptionMenu Method Inside of Class Structure Not Working

Tags: python, tkinter

EDIT::

I am new to using tkinter and I have been having an issue getting the OptionMenu method to work inside of my class structure. If I use Option menu outside of a class it works fine, but for some reason, it does not like my code that is contained in my class. The simplified code I am working with is shown here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.tix import *

class myClass():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('option menu test')

        #create tool bar and set custom color
        toolbarColor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (117, 117, 119)
        self.toolbar = Frame(master, bg=toolbarColor)

        #add instructions button
        self.addInstructionButton = Button(self.toolbar, text='Add Instruction', command=self.addNewFrame)
        self.addInstructionButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=4, pady=4)

        #pack tool bar
        self.toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        #initialize new frames to add and counters
        self.newInstructionCount = 0
        self.newInstructionFrame = []
        self.instructionCloseButton = []
        self.instructionFrame = Frame(self.master,height=410,width=780)
        self.instructionFrame.pack(side=TOP)

    def addNewFrame(self):
        #create new frame and append
        self.newInstructionFrame.append(Frame(self.instructionFrame, width=785, height=100,bd=1,relief=SUNKEN)) #width and height are pixels
        tempFrame = self.newInstructionFrame
        self.instructionFrame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.instructionFrame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.newInstructionFrame[self.newInstructionCount].pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
        #add drop down menu for modifications
        self.modChoices  = ['option 0',
            'option 1',
            'option 2',
            'option 3',
            'option 4',
            'option 5']
        self.modStringVar = StringVar()

        ##### OPTION MENU ERROR HERE #####
        self.modPopupMenu = OptionMenu(tempFrame,StringVar(),self.modStringVar,self.modChoices[0],*self.modChoices)

        self.modLabel     = Label(self.newInstructionFrame[self.newInstructionCount], text='Option Label')
        self.modLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.modPopupMenu.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.newInstructionCount = self.newInstructionCount+1

## MAIN ##
root = Tk()
runGUI = myClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

File "C:/Users/me/Desktop/myFolder/myProject/GUI_code.py", line 192, in addNewFrame

self.modPopupMenu = OptionMenu(tempFrame,StringVar(),self.modStringVar,self.modChoices[0],*self.modChoices)

TypeError: **init**() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 11 were given

Any help or insight here on this error would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time!

Sam

Comment: Please fix the indentation and syntax errors to make it runnable

Comment: Question. is `self.UpdateStatusBar('Adding new instruction...')` referring to a function/method? if so it does not exist. This statement is preventing further testing along with other errors. I can't even begin to troubleshoot the `OptionMenu` problem until your other errors are resolved.

Comment: Show us the full error. I suspect you made a class somewhere named "OptionMenu" and overrode the one that tkinter provides.

Comment: Sorry about the code issues. I have fixed the code and edited the above entry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did override the OptionMenu. By using the evil wildcard imports, you overrode the OptionMenu from tkinter with the OptionMenu from tix. But you are still using the syntax from the tkinter OptionMenu. Use proper imports:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import tix
```

Then if you want to use the tkinter version:

```
self.modPopupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(tempFrame,StringVar(),self.modStringVar,self.modChoices[0],*self.modChoices)
```

BTW tix is deprecated, and python recommends you use ttk instead.